# How to upload images to portfolio using landing pages

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

How to upload images to portfolio using a landing page, I tried the following but it is only taking in from an URL but not from the local machine. Could anyone guide me on how to achieve this?

Processing page:

```
%%[
SET @Image = RequestParameter("fileToUpload")

SET @PortfolioObject = CreateObject("Portfolio")
 SetObjectProperty(@PortfolioObject, "DisplayName", GUID())
 SetObjectProperty(@PortfolioObject, "CustomerKey", GUID())
 SetObjectProperty(@PortfolioObject, "FileName", "example.png")

SET @ClientID = CreateObject("ClientID")
 SetObjectProperty(@ClientID, "ID", "xxxxxxx")
 SetObjectProperty(@PortfolioObject, "Client", @ClientID )

SET @ResourceSpecification = CreateObject("ResourceSpecification")
 SetObjectProperty(@ResourceSpecification, "URN", @Image)
 SetObjectProperty(@PortfolioObject, "Source", @ResourceSpecification)

SET @StatusCode = InvokeCreate(@PortfolioObject, @StatusMsg, @ErrorCode)
]%%

%%=v(@StatusCode)=%%
```

HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="text" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" size="50"> <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to Base64 encrypt your file that is uploaded via the form you have. Check this [Stack Exchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript) for some client-side JS options to handle this.

> Try the solution using the FileReader class:
>
> ```
> function getBase64(file) {    var reader = new FileReader();   
>  reader.readAsDataURL(file);    reader.onload = function () {
>       console.log(reader.result);    };    reader.onerror = function (error) {
>       console.log('Error: ', error);    }; }     
>  var file = document.querySelector('#files >
>  input[type="file"]').files[0]; getBase64(file); // prints the base64
>  string
> ```
>
> Notice that .files[0] is a File type, which is a sublcass of
>   Blob. Thus it can be used with FileReader. See the complete working
>   example.

After it is Base64 encoded, you will need to create a [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm) Content Builder call [Create Asset](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm#detail_CreateAsset) - (POST /asset/v1/content/assets)

This would need to be added into the JSON Body as File:

> File   |   string   |   Base64-encoded string of a file associated with an asset

Simple Sample of the JSON body:

```
{
  "CustomerKey" : "ExternalKeyofFile",
  "AssetType" : {
    "name": "FileType",
    "id" : ID_Number_for_FileType
    },
  "Name" : "Test_Img",
  "File" : "YOUR_BASE64_FILE"
  }
```