# Can I upload a file to Salesforce CRM using AMPScript from a server side Cloud Page?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, fileupload

We want to make a form using Clod Page that will allow the users to upload an excel.
Then we want to upload that excel to our Salesforce CRM.

I found a few ways to send the file to MC server-side page that I will create, for example using Base64 encrypt and posting it.
As explained in this posts:

1. [sfmarketing.cloud](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2020/02/29/create-a-cloudpages-form-with-an-image-file-upload-option/)
2. [stackexchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197455/how-to-upload-images-to-portfolio-using-landing-pages)

I'm wondering, is there a designated AMPScript API function to upload it to SF CRM?
Or must I use a full REST API call from SFMC to SF CRM?

Comment: There is not an ampscript function

Comment: You can't without calling the SF API directly